# How to use FBProphet within Databricks?

Tags: python, installation, databricks, facebook-prophet

I have tried installing the FBProphet within a Databricks notebook in the following ways:

`dbutils.library.installPyPI('FBProphet', version='0.5')`

`pip install fbprophet`

The first line of code has the error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1552.addIsolatedPyPILibrary.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Process List(/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-d8a840a2-8b99-410b-a9c8-0b04a40153ab/bin/python, /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-d8a840a2-8b99-410b-a9c8-0b04a40153ab/bin/pip, install, FBProphet==0.5, --disable-pip-version-check) exited with code 1. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httpstan<4.7,>=4.6 (from pystan>=2.14->FBProphet==0.5) (from versions: 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.10.1, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.2.1, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for httpstan<4.7,>=4.6 (from pystan>=2.14->FBProphet==0.5)

And the second line has the error:

com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.conda.NotebookEnvironmentException: Notebook environment commands (eg %pip) cannot be used in the same notebook as dbutils.library commands. Please ensure your notebook only uses one of these two types of commands, then detach and re-attach the notebook to run this command.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the first one because from the error:

> "dbutils.library APIs are deprecated and will be removed in a future
> DBR release. You can use %pip commands to install notebook-scoped
> python libraries."

And for the second one, according to the installations instructions on [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html),

> As of v1.0, the package name on PyPI is “prophet”; prior to v1.0 it
> was “fbprophet”

So, you should use `pip install prophet` instead of `pip install fbprophet`